# Pine Script - how to add filter from the higher time frame

Tags: pine-script

I have the code below which would add filter based on my current (15min) chart time frame. My question is, how can I add to it to also look for the same but on 1hr chart? In other words, 15min chart and one hour chart would give me a signal to go long ONLY when s21ema > s50ema and s50ema > s200sma and when on 15min chart, s10ema crossover s21ema?.
The opposit would be for a short signal

```
longCond = crossover(s10ema, s21ema) and (s21ema > s50ema) and (s50ema > s200sma)
shortCond = crossunder(s10ema, s21ema) and (s21ema < s50ema) and (s50ema < s200sma)
```

Comment: Have a look at the security() function.

Comment: Awesome... Thank you and much appreciated :-)